# Simulink state-space block giving only one output in MIMO model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have state-space model where:

A is 4x4 matrix, B is 4x1 matrix, C is 1x4 matrix.

I want that model to be simulated in Simulink, simple right? So I made a model as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMfMR.png).

Why i am getting only one output? Shouldnt I get output of matrix 4x1 therefore four outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzing the state space model consisting of system of matrix equations:

```
dx = A*x + B*u
y  = C*x + D*u
```

We can see that size of y (the output) is determined by the number of rows in C and D matrices (number of rows in both matrices must be equal).

In your case `size(C) = [1,4]`, that is the number of rows is 1 so you have only one output.

If you want to extract the whole state you can set `C = eye(4)` and modify D so that `size(D) = [4,1]` (as you have 4 outputs now and 1 input).